# Graph not being displayed in the output of python script

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a small graph plotting code written in python using matplotlib and the graph is not being displayed output. The script works fine. I have added print statements at the end and it works fine, however the graph doesn't show up. Can you please help?
Following is the code snippet I have used for plotting:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title("BPD")
ax.set_xlabel('D')
ax.set_ylabel('P')
plt.savefig("DP.png")
plt.pause(5)
plt.show(block== False)
plt.close()
```

Comment: Are you trying to plot an empty graph? As you are just plotting title and labels.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `plt.pause(5)`, `plt.show(block== False)` and `plt.close()` from your code